# Hide and Show balance with icon click JavaScript

Tags: javascript, icons, hide, show

Please I need help with this JavaScript code, this is what I want it to look like, the balance will be visible and the icon will show as a show icon, and when it is clicked on, the icon will switch to a hide icon and the balance will become password format...
Here is my code below:

```js
function changeIcon(anchor) {
  var icon = anchor.querySelector("i");
  icon.classList.toggle('bx-show');
  icon.classList.toggle('bx-hide');
  anchor.querySelector("span").textContent = icon.classList.contains('bx-show') ? "Read more" : anchor.querySelector("span");
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<a onclick="changeIcon(this)" id="myBtn">
  <i id="faPlus" class='bx bx-show'></i>
  <span class="SPN">Balance: $56,756.00</span>
</a>
```

This is the result, at the first the balance will be visible but when click to hide and click to show the balance again will not be visible, this is what I got as result below:

```
[object HTMLSpanElement]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result isn't working, because you try to set the TextContent of your SPAN-Element to the entire Element itself.

Firstly, you should store the Balance in a separate variable or preferably as a data-attribute for the specific element to access it at any time, cause if you change the TextContent, your Balance value is replace by your "Read more"-String and the original value is gone.

I would oppose the following changes:

- Store the balance in a separate value, to access the value if you want to show the balance again, if it was hidden before.
- You need to change the ternary-operator a little

Ive edited your source code below with comments:

```js
function changeIcon(anchor) {
  var icon = anchor.querySelector("i");
  icon.classList.toggle('bx-show');
  icon.classList.toggle('bx-hide');

  // Changed the falsy state of the ternary operator to return the balance value
  anchor.querySelector("span").textContent = icon.classList.contains('bx-show') ? "Read more" : anchor.querySelector("span").dataset.value;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<a onclick="changeIcon(this)" id="myBtn">
  <i id="faPlus" class='bx bx-show'></i>
  <!-- In php the line would be:
  <span class="SPN" data-value="<?php echo $x; ?>"><?php echo $x; ?></span> -->
  <span class="SPN" data-value="Balance: $56,756.00">Balance: $56,756.00</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I do not recommend saving the balance outside. Instead save the balance on the element like [I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73217946/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan I can see, why this could be of an advantage, but are there some resources on why this would be a better solution. I'm still at the beginning of a programmer, and are eager to learn those finesses.

Comment: It is very likely that there will be more than ONE of these on the page. We might as well prepare for that. In this SPECIFIC case not since there is querySelector instead of querySelectorAll

Comment: Also you have to click twice on the eye now

Comment: That issue resolves of the way the OP set the true/false show logic. And you are absolutely right, the global variable might collide with any other global variable and multiple rows with this functionality would also collide. I've changed the solution.

Comment: But that is my solution you just copied - OP accepted your initial solution  - if he still likes your changed solution then he should accept mine instead

Comment: I would delete my answer, as yours is the only valid one. I dont assume that OP would change the accepted answer as he wont get back to his question. I'm sorry.

Comment: @IISkullsII can i make the span display in two separate div?

Comment: The Two answer was fine, you don't have to delete it i make use of both, and someone can still fine either useful thanks to both of you

Answer (score 3):

You need the textContent of the span, but then it is gone after you replace it.

I also swapped the test since you had to click twice on the eye

I suggest you use a data attribute (or toggle two spans, the read and the balance)

If you have more than one, we need to delegate (see further down)

```js
function changeIcon(anchor) {
  var icon = anchor.querySelector("i");
  icon.classList.toggle('bx-show');
  icon.classList.toggle('bx-hide');
  anchor.querySelector("span").textContent = icon.matches('.bx-hide') ? "Read more" : anchor.querySelector("span").dataset.text;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<a onclick="changeIcon(this)" id="myBtn">
  <i id="faPlus" class='bx bx-show'></i>
  <span class="SPN" data-text="Balance: $56,756.00">Balance: $56,756.00</span>
</a>
```

More than one element:

```js
document.getElementById("balances").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("a"); // wee can click anywhere in the anchor
  if (!tgt.matches(".myBtn")) return // not a button
  const icon = tgt.querySelector("i");
  const span = tgt.querySelector("span");
  icon.classList.toggle('bx-show');
  icon.classList.toggle('bx-hide');
  span.textContent = icon.matches('.bx-hide') ? "Read more" : span.dataset.text;
})
```

```html
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<div id="balances">
  <a class="myBtn">
    <i class='bx bx-show'></i>
    <span class="SPN" data-text="Balance: $56,756.00">Balance: $56,756.00</span>
  </a>
  <hr/>
  <a class="myBtn">
    <i class='bx bx-show'></i>
    <span class="SPN" data-text="Balance: $55,756.00">Balance: $55,756.00</span>
  </a>
</div>
```